# ListView with relative layout and scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am using a scrollview in which i have added 3 relative layout and a list so the stack is like

> - Scrollview
>
>   - Relative Layout
>   - Relative Layout
>   - ______   ListView
>   - Relative Layout

Now when i am trying to add entries in listview it is now increasing its height. I have set wrap_content for the height field.

Comment: what is the problem you facing here?

Comment: never use listview inside scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Use only listView and add the relativeLayouts as headers/footers.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the height of listview because you are using scrollview

you can scroll and view that list while scrolling content inside listview.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what you are saying here.  Can you explain some more?

Comment: You issues is listview size is getting increased. So better fix the size of listview android:layout_height="200dp" . Listview size will be fixed .and you can add other views bottom of listview

Comment: Another way inside scrollview add linerlayout and define weight  for listview like this android:layout_height="0" and android:weight = "1" if weight sum is 2 for example

Comment: It is better if that information is in the answer.  Can you edit it?